# Is it possible to get a unique identifier for an ios device from a browser, in a controlled environment?

Tags: ios, browser, uniqueidentifier

This is (a very simplified version of) the scenario with which I am faced:

I have an existing web application which manages jobs. We are now purchasing a number of ios devices (iphones and ipads) and I need the web application to know which specific device (regardless of the user) is updating information through the web application (as well as getting the GPS co-ordinates, but I think I have that covered with the geolocation API).

I have control of all the devices, they will all come to me before being distributed and will return to me periodically, so I can modify/restrict etc., but I can't jailbreak.

I have no experience of ios, but if there is a way to do this without needing an app, that would be the best choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [HTML5 storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) to create and save a GUID the first time user accesses your website and send it with subsequent requests.